# How to insert an item into an array using REST and node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, rest

I'm using node to store items in a Firebase database, using a REST API. What I don't understand is how to append an item in an array. So for instance to append new items to the database I'm using PATCH:

```
const https = require('https');
var patchData = '{"thing":"value"}';

var options = {
    host: 'mydatabase.firebaseio.com',
    path: '/items.json',
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(patchData)
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Body: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        //do end clean up
    });
});

req.on("error", function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ', e.message);
});

//write data to request body
req.write(patchData);
req.end();
```

I can append or replace objects no problem and get a structure like this:

```
{
    "items": {
        "thing1": "value1",
        "thing2": "value2",
        "thing3": "value3"
    }
}
```

The structure I want is this:

```
{
    "items": [{"thing1": "value1"},
        {"thing2": "value2"},
        {"thing3": "value3"}]
}
```

As each item is roughly a collection of the same sort of thing, and not attributes of the items objects.

Either I'm missing something simple, or the entire array needs to be first read, then appended to in node, and rewritten back to Firebase in one go, but that seems incredibly inefficient. How do I get the second structure?

Comment: i ddnt found object which has items, share object modfication code

Comment: That is the correct code. You would have to use different values to keep appending to the items object. Also, you would need to use your own Firebase database.